# Camera intent crashing my application after few pictures

Tags: java, android, android-intent, camera, crash

I am having a problem with some phones during coming back from android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE. On HTC and Alcatel it works great, but on LG it crashes my application. I can save some pictures and after that my application crashes with Sorry! MyApplication has stoped. I have tried many ways how to avoid this but i still get the same error.

First i was using this

1: attempt

Taking picture with image path (not getting any exception):

```
public static void saveImage(String saveImgDir, String image, int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE, Activity activity) {
        try {
            GlobalVariables.incorrectButtonPressed = false;
             // CREATE DIR IF NOT EXISTS
             File directory = new File(saveImgDir);
             directory.mkdirs();
             // CREATE AND SAVE IMG
             File imageFile = new File(saveImgDir + File.separator + image);
             try {
             imageFile.createNewFile();
             } catch (IOException e) {
             Log.d("IMG", "FILE CREATE: " + e.toString(), e.getCause());
             }
             Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
             // CALL CAMERA ACTIVITY
             Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
             cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
             activity.startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("CAMPROBLEM", "bblockScenario", ex);
        }

    }
```

On activity result (not getting any exception):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    try {
    if (requestCode == B_TAKE_PHOTO_CODE_AFTER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Log.d("CAMPROBLEM", "ACTIVITY RESULT B_TAKE_PHOTO_CODE_AFTER RESULT OK");
        imageTakenAfter++;
        Toast.makeText(context, "PCITURE SAVED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).
        return;
        }
        if (requestCode == B_TAKE_PHOTO_CODE_AFTER && resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d("CAMPROBLEM", "ACTIVITY RESULT B_TAKE_PHOTO_CODE_AFTER RESULT NOT OK");
            Toast.makeText(context, "PCITURE NOT SAVED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d("CAMPROBLEM", "bblockScenario", ex);
    }

}
```

2: attempt

Then i tried using async tasks (just to make sure that is not a memory leak). I called The saveImage function from AsyncTask class and still got the same problem. (not getting any eceptions)

3: attempt

Calling the intent without the image save path:

```
public static void saveImage(int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE, Activity activity) {
        try {
            GlobalVariables.incorrectButtonPressed = false;
            // CREATE DIR IF NOT EXISTS
            Intent it = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            activity.startActivityForResult(it, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("CAMPROBLEM", "bblockScenario", ex);
        }

    }
```

And saving my picture in my onActivityResult

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        try {
            String image = ServerTime.getServerDate() + ".jpg";
            File file = new File(saveImgDirectory + File.separator + image);
            try {
                if (data == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "IMAGE NOT SAVED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    bblockScenario();
                    Log.d("CAMPROBLEM", "NULL DATA");
                    return;
                }
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                FileOutputStream out = null;

                out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "IMAGE NOT SAVED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                bblockScenario();
                Log.d("CAMPROBLEM", "E", e);
                return;
            } finally {
                try {

                } catch (Throwable ignore) {
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(context, "IMAGE SAVED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("CAMPROBLEM", "bblockScenario", ex);
        }

    }
```

Here in onActivityResult i get null data on every 3th picture. Cant figure why.

I have all the premision in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
```

Any help and knowledge of this problem will make my life easier. Hope that someone can help me.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Logcat:

```
05-23 10:26:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(14022): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-23 10:26:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(14022): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
05-23 10:26:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(14022):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.findViewLocked(WindowManagerImpl.java:671)
05-23 10:26:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(14022):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:364)
05-23 10:26:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(14022):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:163)
05-23 10:26:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(14022):    at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:347)
05-23 10:26:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(14022):    at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:330)
05-23 10:26:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(14022):    at es.zonsko.bitola.blocator.activity.BlocatorTabHostActivity$SyncTask.onPostExecute(BlocatorTabHostActivity.java:381)
05-23 10:26:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(14022):    at es.zonsko.bitola.blocator.activity.BlocatorTabHostActivity$SyncTask.onPostExecute(BlocatorTabHostActivity.java:1)
05-23 10:26:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(14022):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
05-23 10:26:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(14022):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
05-23 10:26:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(14022):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
05-23 10:26:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(14022):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-23 10:26:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(14022):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
05-23 10:26:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(14022):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5070)
05-23 10:26:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(14022):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-23 10:26:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(14022):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-23 10:26:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(14022):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
05-23 10:26:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(14022):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
05-23 10:26:17.412: E/AndroidRuntime(14022):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: The application is at my work computer, ill edit this post tomorrow with logcat.

Comment: @interlude The post is edited and contains the logcat

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this exception in onActivityResult, please use below code at start of your onActivityResult()

```
if(resultcode != RESULT_OK)
return;
```

Comment: If you are writing about my third solution, yess i can. I can also make the user take every picture 2, 3 times before i save it, but that's not what i am looking for.

Comment: This doesn't even attempt to answer the question. It should be a comment, and not a very good one.